# To get Mail work for `git am`

Tags: macos, git, apple-mail

I use Gmail and Mac's Mail for emails.
It seems that you can use `git am` only with a terminal's Mail in OS X/Ubuntu.

I apparently need to set up my ~/.mailrc such that

```
# gmail account
account gmail {
set from="masi.masi@gmail.com (Masi Masi)"
set sendmail="/usr/bin/msmtp"
set message-sendmail-extra-arguments="-a gmail"
}
```

I run

```
mail bill.bill@yahoo.com
```

I get

```
Unknown command: "account"
```

**How can you use Gmail for Mail** such that I get my mails' patches to `git am`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use fetchmail to get the emails from your google account into mbox/maildir .

Comment: Please, see http://superuser.com/questions/11070/to-get-mail-work-for-git-am/11097#11097

Answer (score 2):

**Reply to [the answer](https://superuser.com/questions/11070/to-get-mail-work-for-git-am/11080#11080):**

I [found](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/linux/RHL-7.3-Manual/ref-guide/s1-email-fetchmail.html) that I need to have the .fetchmailrc such that

```
set postmaster "masi"
set bouncemail

poll pop.gmail.com proto pop3
     user 'masi.masi@gmail.com' there with password 'secret' is masi here
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried having *Mail* export the messages to an mbox file?

1. Select the messages in *Mail*.
2. File > Save As…

   - Format: Raw Message Source

The result should be an mbox file.

---

In *Mail*'s help, I found the following under “Backing up your email” (first result when searching for “mbox”):

> To create an mbox file with just some of your messages, select the messages, then choose File > Save As. In the Format pop-up menu, choose Raw Message Source, then enter a name and save the file.

---

There are [some reports](http://diveintomark.org/archives/2006/07/13/mail-checks-in) of the resulting file not being in a true mbox format (there are actually [several not-quite compatible mbox formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox#Family)).

The reported problem was that "From " lines in the content of plain-text messages were not escaped. For such lines my version of *Mail* writes " From " instead of the more typical ">From ", but they are escaped. In the context of emailed Git patches, this should only be a problem for the commit message, but you might look out for it all the same (no matter which path you take to get your emails into mbox format for *git am*).